# Obtaining Delay for Calendar Schedule Format

Tags: java, calendar, cron, logic

I'm working on a project that allows users to input a task that follows a format similar to cron. Currently, I need to be able to determine when the next time the task should be run and get the number of seconds until that time. Here are a couple examples of the format being used and the expected outcomes.

```
Format: (second) (minute) (hour) (day) (month)
          0-59     0-59    0-23   1-31  1-12

(##): States the exact value for the parameter
(*): Accepts all values (effectively ignores the parameter)

Step Modifier (/##): Considers all whole number multiples of ##

30 * * * * -> Runs a task every minute when second = 30
0 /5 * * * -> Runs a task every 5 minutes (at 0, 5, 10, etc.) when second = 0
13 /15 /2 * * -> Runs a task every 15 minutes when seconds = 13 and hour is even
```

Here are a couple examples of what I need to do to parse this.

```
Example time: July 6th, 5:34:12 (24 hour)
In modified format: 12 34 5 6 7

30 * * * * -> returns 18 (next task runs at 5:34:30)
0 /5 * * * -> returns 48 (next task runs at 5:35:00)
13 /15 /2 * * -> returns 1561 (next task runs at 6:00:13)
```

I've tried a bunch of different approaches and have even brought it to my instructor and other students however no one has been able to devise a solution. The programming is the easy part, but it's the logic that evades me. If anyone can offer a suggestion, I'd be extremely grateful.

*The only library I'd like to use is `java.util.Calendar` which simply gets the current time, then using `Calendar.getInstance().SECONDS` or other time units.*

Answer (score 0):

Simple strategy:

- Convert step values and wildcards in schedule to lists, for example `0 0 /6 1 *` becomes `0 0 0,5,11,17,23 1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`.
- Make a new date initialized to now.
- Does the month match one of the schedule's months? If not, increment the date's month until it does match.
- Then check the day; does it match one of the schedule's days? If not, increment it until it does match.
- Then check the hour...
- And so on until the whole date matches the schedule.
- Then subtract the current date from that matching date to get the delay.

Comment: I actually gave up on it after a while and never thought to check back here until now since I've opened it up again. The issue with this is the overlap - if the schedule needs to wrap around an hour; this method fails. This is made even more difficult due to the step modifier as described above. Unfortunately, this is far from a simple strategy.

Comment: @JayCastell I've updated my answer to help you with step values. I don't believe overlap is a problem if you follow my strategy. But maybe I'm missing something and you can give an example where this would fail.